# Right hand side of APEX Shuttle Page Item, not being retained in Dynamic Action

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page item :P1_STUDY_SEARCH and a shuttle :P1_STUDY_CODES

The query driving the shuttle looks as below:

```
SELECT 
   DISTINCT
    D.INTERNAL_REF_NO AS d,
    D.INTERNAL_REF_NO AS v
    FROM 
ARIEL.DIM_DRUG_PRODUCT A,
ARIEL.DIM_REGISTRATION_SET B,
ARIEL.v_rep_includes C,
ARIEL.dim_registration_additional D
WHERE 
A.DRUG_PRODUCT_ID = B.DRUG_PRODUCT_ID
    AND 
B.VERSION_SEQ = C.VERSION_SEQ
    AND 
B.REGISTRATION_SET_ID = D.REGISTRATION_SET_ID
    AND
B.APPLICATION_TYPE IN ('CAT','DOG')
    AND 
B.DATA_STATE = 'C'
    AND 
D.INTERNAL_REF_NO IS NOT NULL
    AND
D.INTERNAL_REF_NO LIKE 'D%'
    AND
LENGTH(D.INTERNAL_REF_NO) >=10
    AND
1 = (CASE WHEN :P1_STUDY_SEARCH IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE
        CASE WHEN D.INTERNAL_REF_NO LIKE '%' || :P1_STUDY_SEARCH || '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END)
ORDER BY 1;
```

This query restricts the values in the left hand side of the shuttle based on the values of the search term.

The shuttle source SQL is a colon delimited list:

SELECT LISTAGG(STUDY_CODE,':') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY STUDY_CODE)
FROM GRET_STUDIES WHERE GRET_ID = :P1_GRET GROUP BY GRET_ID

This all works beautifully, until a dynamic action is called which is attached to the :P1_STUDY_SEARCH item.  On Key down in this search field, the dynamic action refreshes the :P1_STUDY_CODES page item.

The idea is the list gets restricted based on the search term.  This part works, but the right hand side of the shuttle loses all of its values.

I suspect the reason is, you cant have ANYTHING in the right hand side of the shuttle (the SOURCE query), if it ISNT also part of the result set in the List of Values query....?  #

This seems quite bad, as the source query is distinct from the LOV query?!

Comment: This is expected behaviour for any list item (whether a shuttle or otherwise); when a list of values is refreshed, the value of the item is cleared. To restore the previous value you'd have to add some custom javascript to re-set the value after the refresh, although you'd have to handle the case where a value that had been selected is no longer in the newly refreshed list of values.

Comment: I am allowing people to edit the list of values and save the list.  It seems if a source record is removed somehow from the LOV query, then it will also disappear from the right hand side despite having a record in the database which the source query should return.  If the user then saves the list, they accidentally lose a record.  I thought 'display extra values' would solve this.

Comment: You have to understand that these are not "records", it's a single field that happens to have some internal structure (i.e. a colon-delimited list of strings) but it's still a single value.

Comment: OK, but why things cant exist on the right when they are not part of the LOV data on the left is a bit of a flaw.  As you say, if I unpack 3 values on the right from a colon delimited string -  and it only shows me 1 of them, because the other 2 are not part of the LOV query - it isnt great for doing DB recall into a shuttle.